# Memoize my recursive coinSums

Tags: javascript, recursion, dynamic-programming, memoization

I have a basic `coinSums` recursive function:

```
function coinSums(total) {      
    var coins = [1, 5, 10, 25];
    var output = [];
    var memo={} <--the only part im sure about :)
    function subroutine(pos, runningSum, currentCombo) {
        if (total === runningSum) {
            return output.push(currentCombo)
        } else if (total < runningSum) {
            return false
        } else
            for (var i = pos; i < coins.length; i++) {
                subroutine(i, runningSum + coins[i], currentCombo.concat(coins[i]))
            }
    }
    subroutine(0, 0, [])
    return output.length; }
```

I would really like to figure out a way 'memoize' it to improve the `O(n^k)` runtime (`k=num of coins`, `n=target`, right?), but keep it
recursive and not change the recursive call as little as possible. (I need to maintain the combo and `runningSum` bottom up
approach).

I know how to do it with the top down approach. Any genius
have any ideas?

ps We can change the `pos` that `i` in the `for` loop
starts at to 0 to give us the number of ordered combinations. I need
to return the unordered combos which is why I want to maintain the
running combos.

Comment: Note that memoization is a fundamental technique in dynamic-programming in that it can *prevent* recursion if previously invoked with the same arguments. You mentioned preferring to keep the recursion, but then it wouldn't be dynamic programming.

Comment: I don't know the whole problem, but I think you should use `Bit Masking` approach to solve this problem.

Comment: 1. If you are looking for memoization here is the link https://addyosmani.com/blog/faster-javascript-memoization/                                  2. In JS a function is also an object, so you dont have to declare a new object to cache the value . Instead you can use functionName[input] to store the output of the current input.                                                                    3. var memo = {} is an object to store/cache the result of a specific input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid your requirement is impossible to meet unless you want to use memoization for muliple uses of
`coinSums` itself -- in a single application of the former you are calling `subroutine`
with *always* different argument sets, and the one making them unique is `currentCombo`, which I believe cannot be "abstracted from" when memoizing, as it's the core of the whole algorithm...

What you can do is to collect this `output` thing with top-down recursion, which is "nice" for memoization, though that's probably what you already know...

```
function coinSums(total) {
    /// "cache":
    var _coinSumsMem_ = {};
    var lookupCoins = function(total,pos) {
        return _coinSumsMem_[[total,pos]];
    };
    var memoizeCoins=function(total,pos, coins) {
        _coinSumsMem_[[total,pos]]
            = coins.map(function(xs) {return xs.slice();}); /// a clone!
    };
    /// "computation":
    var coinsAvailable = [1,5,10,20];    
    findAll = function(total, pos) {
        if(total<0 || pos==coinsAvailable.length) return [];
        else if(total==0) return [[]];
        var result = lookupCoins(total,pos);
        if(result == undefined) {
            var oneWaySums = findAll(total-coinsAvailable[pos], pos);
            oneWaySums.map(function(xs) {xs.push(coinsAvailable[pos]);});
            var otherWaySums = findAll(total, pos+1);
            result = oneWaySums.concat(otherWaySums);
            memoizeCoins(total,pos, result);
        }
        return result;
    };
    return findAll(total,0).length; /// or without length...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach that uses dynamic programming. For more detailed information about the approach, watch this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jaNZ83Q3QGc.

```
function coinsSum(amount) {
  const coins = [1, 5, 10, 25]
  const combinations = Array(amount + 1).fill(0);
  combinations[0] = 1;
  let count = 0;
  while (count < coins.length) {
    const coin = coins[count];
    for (let i = coin; i < combinations.length; i++) {
      if (amount >= coin) combinations[i] += combinations[i - coin];
    }
    count++;
  }
  return combinations.pop();
}
```